# Why does case_when have two different outputs here?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am failing to understand why the output is different when I use two different cases of case_when:

Option 1:

```
x = 5
y = print("goodmorning")
z = print("goodafternoon")
q = print("goodevening")
case_when(x > 3 ~ y, x < 8 ~ z)
```

Output 1:

```
[1] "goodmorning"
```

Option 2:

```
x = 5
case_when(x > 3 ~ print("goodmoring"), x < 8 ~ print("goodafternoon"))
```

Output 2:

```
[1] "goodmoring"
[1] "goodafternoon"
[1] "goodmoring"
```

Can someone enlighten me how this results in two completely different outputs. I believed that case_when sequentially and that it jumps out of the case_case when the first time the a condition is met and this seems to hold for the first piece of code, but why does it not hold for the second code?

Comment: `case_when` should not be used for conditional evaluation. All the terms will be evaulated. You should not use `functions` like `print()` inside the `case_when`. The `case_when` should return a string value that you `print()`. Like `print(case_when(x > 3 ~ "goodmoring", x < 8 ~ "goodafternoon"))`. in your Option1 your output seems incomplete. The lines where you call `print()` should all be returning output as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing the help page (emphasis mine),

> *case_when() evaluates all RHS expressions*, and then constructs its result by extracting the selected (via the LHS expressions) parts